# Rails App Wicked Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm killing myself trying to solve this routing error.

Some background info: I'm using Ryan Bates' Rails Cast on Wicked Wizard Forms to create a multi-step form. I'm getting a routing error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"user_steps", :action=>"show", :id=>nil}
```

Clearly, the `user.id` isn't being passed through to the subsequent view - any ideas how to solve this?

User Controller Create:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        format.html { redirect_to user_steps_path(@user) }
        #format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }#
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

User Steps Controller (for Wicked)

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard
    steps :gender, :items, :brands, :final

    def show
        render_wizard
    end 

    def update
        @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        render_wizard @user
    end
end
```

Routes:

```
Store::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :likes

  resources :categories

  resources :user_steps

  match "user_steps/gender", to: "user_steps#gender", via: "post"
  resources :users
```

users_steps/gender.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :user, url: wizard_path do |f| %>

<div class="container" align="center">
  <div class="div2" align="center">
    <h2 align="center"> You are a ...</h2>
    <div class="container" align="center">
      <div class="row" align="center">
        <div class="span6">
          <h9>Guy</h9>
          <label for="user_gender_guy"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/bpIMo.png" class="new" width="200" height="500"></label>
          <input checked="checked" id="user_gender_guy" name="user[gender]" type="radio" value="Guy" /> 
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
          <h9>Girl</h9>
          <label for="user_gender_girl"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/xpA1S.png" class="new" width="200" height="500"></label>
          <input checked="checked" id="user_gender_girl" name="user[gender]" type="radio" value="Girl" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div> 
</div>

<%= f.submit "Next" %>
<% end %>
```

Rake Routes:

```
user_steps GET    /user_steps(.:format)          user_steps#index
                  POST   /user_steps(.:format)          user_steps#create
    new_user_step GET    /user_steps/new(.:format)      user_steps#new
   edit_user_step GET    /user_steps/:id/edit(.:format) user_steps#edit
        user_step GET    /user_steps/:id(.:format)      user_steps#show
                  PUT    /user_steps/:id(.:format)      user_steps#update
                  DELETE /user_steps/:id(.:format)      user_steps#destroy
user_steps_gender POST   /user_steps/gender(.:format)   user_steps#gender
```

Comment: Note: `match "user_steps/gender" ...` has to be *above* the `resources :user_steps` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in User controller 
`redirect_to user_steps_path(@user)`

I think this solve your problem.

Comment: Hmmm, I've tried this - doesn't work. See updated code at top.

Comment: what about `rake routes` for `user_step`?

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer if it didn't work? Just curious what you did differently, because I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your user_controller#create method try changing

`redirect_to user_steps_path(@user)`
to

`redirect_to user_steps_path(:gender)`

Also I don't think you need this line in your routes file:

`match "user_steps/gender", to: "user_steps#gender", via: "post"`

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the :id parameter, which wicked uses to control the steps. To pass additional query string arguments, you need to use the second arg (options hash) to user_steps_path, which means you need to supply the :id (step) as the first arg.

```
redirect_to user_steps_path(:gender, :user_id => @user.id)
```

Then in your controller:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    render_wizard
end
```

Finally in your view (don't forget :method => :put);

```
<%= form_for @user, url: wizard_path, method: put do |f| %>
    ...    
<%= f.submit "Next" %>
<% end %>
```

Though not sure why you aren't using the form helper variable f to generate the fields (e.g. <%= f.radio_button :gender, "Guy" %>), but it should still work.